# gradle dosnt update i dont know the problems can i get the helpe

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, updates, wrapper

Gradle DSL method not found: 'google()' Possible causes: The project 'My Application' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0). Upgrade plugin to version 4.0.1 and sync project The project 'My Application' may be usplease

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to `Upgrade plugin to version 4.0.1` and sync project. It will upgrade by clicking text of Upgrade plugin as it automatically navigates towards updating required plugin .

Also

To use the DSL `implementation()` you have to use:

- The updated gradle plugin for Android 3.0.0.
- The gradle version 3.4 or later.

Then in your `build.gradle` you have to use:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
        // You need to add the following repository to download the
        // new plugin.
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta1'
    }
}
```

In your `gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionUrl=\
  https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-rc-1-all.zip
```

More detailed [info here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build).